# Porting ASP.NET to MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor

I am porting a classic ASP.NET application (ASPX pages) to ASP.NET MVC 3. Currently I use ContentPlaceHolder(s) to dynamically add content to specific ASP.NET ASPX pages. Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="MyStyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Styles">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryAndOtherScripts.js"></script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Container">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So in the snippet above I have 3 content place holders so I can add addition styles, scripts and content based on the individual page. The reason I have done it this way is so that each page only loads the styles, scripts relevant to the content on the page (for example if it was the login page, I might add a script to check that the login details are valid)

Consider the following MVC 3 Razor View snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="MyStyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryAndOtherScripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now for the problem...RenderBody() replaces `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`, but what do I use as a replacement for `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Styles"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` and `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` ?

Comment: You'll probably want to use [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) to achieve that.

Comment: @ManuLetroll: You really should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: @ManuLetroll - Yes ! The answer belongs to u dude ! Manu post it as a answer and Matthew should accept that one. Sorry i dint read through the comment and posted in .

Comment: In fact I intended to post an answer but for some reason I commented instead, I wanted to go into a bit more detail but didn't have the time right then. Please accept the existing answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sections` are the way to achieve this. Check out this excellent post by ScottGu on the subject.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: Thanks V much...this is a great help!

Answer (score 3):

There are [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks guys. I really should google it before I ask. I found the answer I was looking for seconds after submitting this post! Cheers.

Comment: @MatthewLayton - Great dude !! Accept the appropriate answer in that case . I would suggest Manu Letroll to answer it , And accept that !